# Restrictive or Non-Restrictive Use of Which?

Tags: american-english, british-english

> Religion is a personal or institutionalized set of attitudes, beliefs
>   and practices, which may include a system of prayers and religious
>   laws.

In the preceding sentence, is 'which' restrictive or non-restrictive and therefore, does it or does it not require a comma before it?

Comment: It could be either. A description of what you want to express might help narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Non-restrictive. A simple test is to remove the clause and see if the sentence can stand on its own without it.

Answer (score 0):

Because your sentence has that comma before 'which,' you have set the clause as non-restrictive. Remove the comma for the restrictive sense of the clause, but it looks like you're expanding on mention of practices to add that the practices may include prayer and rules.

As it stands, your description is somewhat circular, "Religion... may include... religious laws." Perhaps find another word for religious laws, such as restrictions or ritual laws known as *shariah* or *halacha*.